# Run mobile web application in the background as a service

Tags: android, ios, html, mobile

I am working on a HTML5 mobile web application that runs in browser. I want this app to receive server sent push notifications even when the browser/web app is closed. For that reason, I would want my mobile web app to run in the background once visited. I mean I will store some code on mobile maybe cache etc. So the question is that **is it possible to run mobile web app as a service on mobile device?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in iOS, you can let your web application run in background (when it is closed). You have to give some settings to your application. However, in background, the UI threads is suspended, all commands in UI thread will be cached, until you open your application again. So remember to process your services in background threads, else they will be stucked with UI thread.

In Android, you can even create a service (without interface) and let it execute separately from your main application.

For another platform, I don't know the answer.

Comment: For android, as you mentioned creating service, does that mean I need to write that service using Java?

Comment: Yes, you write your service using Java. However, I don't know if it's a pure Java service or it is a Android base Java service. Anyhow, I think that java used for Android may have less functionalities as stand Java for PC. I don't have much experience in Android. I find this: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Thanks for that however, as I mentioned I am working on mobile web app that runs purely on browsers using HTML5 and JavaScript. I am not using any Java and Object C/Swift. I want to make my scenario happen using web technologies only.

Comment: With web (javascript) technology, I think that it's possible to create a kind of socket connection between your application and a server in order to exchange command/answer.  However, this is not the same Service as per my answer. In order to use this kind of Service, you have at least implement that Service in java, then from your javascript, you can invoke to that Service by using JavaScript-Java bridge. Search in google, you will find some ready-to-use plugins

Comment: That is something I am thinking and searching. For android it may work however for iOS it may not because iOS only allows to download and install apps from appstore only unless if they are jailbroken but I am not looking for jailbroken users.

Comment: If you aren't familiar with Java, you may have a look at [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)

Comment: @momo I am not building native app by using Titanium/Phonegap. It is pure web app using front end technology. :)

Comment: On the Android side, I suggest that it isn't possible to run a web app on background. The rule states that you can't run something on background that has a user interface. So as above-mentioned, you have to create an Android Service. As far as I know, browsers like Chrome or the Android Browser will be paused (JavaScript, flash etc.) as soon as the UI isn't visible to the user (e.g. user launched a new app)

Answer (score -1):

On iOS you can set a [web page to run as a web app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW3). There is even an SO tag for [iphone standalone web apps](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iphone-standalone-web-app/info), and the overview explains it nicely.

Here is the equivalent for Android - [Add to homescreen](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen)

Comment: This is true but the answer is not relevant to the question asked. The question asked is how to run some application logic in the background. Your answer is attempting to answer how to RUN a PWA(Progressive Web App) on IPhone.